# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'animate' in Fabric.js 1.4.0

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I use Fabric.js 1.3.0 in my current project and wanted to update the library to version 1.4.0.

When I run my code I get this warning:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'animate'
```

It seems that the image is not fully loaded yet to be animated. Otherwise I suppose I wouldn't get this error. But I don't understand why it's working with version 1.3.0 then.

I use the [checkAllLoaded function from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939782/fabric-js-problem-with-drawing-multiple-images-zindex) to make sure all my images are loaded before I start animating.

Did something change from version 1.3.0 to 1.4.0 regarding this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you built it without animation module? 1.4.0 is used on fabricjs.com and animate works in all the demos (e.g. http://fabricjs.com/animation-easing/)

Comment: I used the "Custom Build" option [from the fabric.js website](http://fabricjs.com/build/). There I selected all checkboxes and downloaded fabric.js in version 1.4.0. So the animation module should have been included. When downloading version 1.4.0 from [Github](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/releases/tag/v1.4.0) everything works fine. Since I used version 1.3.0 before everything breaks in orientation as expected, because the x- and y-orientation is now left and top and not center anymore. Another point is that the demos use version 1.4.3. This version works for me except event handling.